# autohotkey: copy file name without Path and Extension

Tags: loops, parameters, path, copy, autohotkey

Welcome everyone

The following code frome here: https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=44848

Written by: Odlanir

```
        q::
    fileselected := Explorer_GetSelection()
    SplitPath,fileselected, fn
    MsgBox % "FileName :`t" fn "`nFullName :`t" fileselected
    clipboard = % "FileName :`t" fn "`nFullName :`t" fileselected
    return


    Explorer_GetSelection(hwnd="") {
        WinGet, process, processName, % "ahk_id" hwnd := hwnd? hwnd:WinExist("A")
        WinGetClass class, ahk_id %hwnd%
        if (process = "explorer.exe")
            if (class ~= "Progman|WorkerW") {
                ControlGet, files, List, Selected Col1, SysListView321, ahk_class %class%
                Loop, Parse, files, `n, `r
                ToReturn .= A_Desktop "\" A_LoopField "`n"
        } else if (class ~= "(Cabinet|Explore)WClass") {
            for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
                if (window.hwnd==hwnd)
                    sel := window.Document.SelectedItems
            for item in sel
                ToReturn .= item.path "`n"
        }
    return Trim(ToReturn,"`n")


}
return
```

When you click the Hotkey we get the filename and path for selected files, 
As the picture appears attached

[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VvPKYrbVQEfrmdB34dUND9HbnXMl0Lr2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48ucB.png)

my question is: How do I get a list by filename only, Without File Path and File Extension 
As the picture appears attached

[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rCuLikjqT8Nudipby5Y9MOHTqdozGPYn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyvme.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New edited code:

```
q::
fileselected := Explorer_GetSelection()
MsgBox % fileselected
clipboard = % fileselected
return


Explorer_GetSelection(hwnd="") {
    WinGet, process, processName, % "ahk_id" hwnd := hwnd? hwnd:WinExist("A")
    WinGetClass class, ahk_id %hwnd%
    if (process = "explorer.exe")
        if (class ~= "Progman|WorkerW") {
            ControlGet, files, List, Selected Col1, SysListView321, ahk_class %class%
            Loop, Parse, files, `n, `r
            ToReturn .= A_Desktop "\" A_LoopField "`n"
    } else if (class ~= "(Cabinet|Explore)WClass") {
        for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
            if (window.hwnd==hwnd)
                sel := window.Document.SelectedItems
        for item in sel
            ToReturn .= item.path "`n"
    }
 fileselected:=ToReturn . "`n"
 while RegExMatch(fileselected,"s)\\(.*)")
 {
 RegExMatch(fileselected,"s)(.*?)(\n)",filestemp)
 RegExMatch(filestemp,"(.*)\.",filestemp)
  while RegExMatch(filestemp1,"s)\\(.*)")
   RegExMatch(filestemp1,"s)\\(.*)",filestemp)
 filesfin := filesfin . filestemp1 . "`n"
 RegExMatch(fileselected,"\n(.*)",filestemp)
 fileselected:=filestemp1
 }
 return (filesfin)


}
return
```

Comment: Hi, Roman
I have lost the most important feature in the code is to deal with any number of selected files
Now the code displays only one file name.
It does not work.

Comment: Hi, Roman
you have saved me a lot of time and effort
You are truly awesome
Great help, and a commendable initiative
THANK YOU very much

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution could be to just edit one line:

```
SplitPath fileselected, fNameExt, fDir, fExt, fName, fDrv
```

and then use `fName` or any other results any way you want.

You could, of course, just omit other parameters:

```
SplitPath fileselected,,,, fName
```

Comment: My first solution was very similar to this but it didn't work correctly because fName only returns first selected file and fileselected returns all files.

Comment: Oh you're right, Roman. I missed the OP's comment on your answer.

Comment: Hi, johnlee, Thank you for your excellent initiative, You taught me something new,  THANK YOU very much